# Polylines drawn between two points in google map is not on Road( driving directions)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, polyline

How to enable driving directions in google map with polylines. Can any one help to make to draw map over road between two points.

Currently a simple line is drawn between two points in map. I am unable to change it.

My code is given below

```
        String stringUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + fromPosition+ "&destination=" + toPosition+ "&sensor=false";
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            if (httpconn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()),
                        8192);
                String strLine = null;

                while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(strLine);
                }
                input.close();
            }

            String jsonOutput = response.toString();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonOutput);

            // routesArray contains ALL routes
            JSONArray routesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
            // Grab the first route
            JSONObject route = routesArray.getJSONObject(0);

            JSONArray legs = route.getJSONArray("legs");
            JSONObject firtsLegs = legs.getJSONObject(0);

            JSONObject distance = firtsLegs.getJSONObject("distance");


            System.out.println("Response test was : " + distance.getString("text"));

            String walkDistance = distance.getString("text");



            JSONObject poly = route.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            String polyline = poly.getString("points");
            decodePoly(polyline);


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON object return by Google Direction API. It needs to decode all points in the polyline for complete navigation. 
You can either write parsing logic by yourself or can take help from some cool existing projects like https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary.

Comment: Adding a 3 rd party library is not secure in this terms. So I am trying to do it in android map's native feature. Thanks for your comments.